# Frequent WiFi disconnects on laptop

Tags: windows, networking, performance, routing, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Frequent WiFi disconnects on laptop when not charged](https://superuser.com/questions/442963/frequent-wifi-disconnects-on-laptop-when-not-charged)

I have a weird wireless connection problem. The whole thing started today, when I installed my new router a D-Link DIR635 model after my previous router became very unreliable and faulty. I use this router the share a wired internet connection between a PC, a PS3, and to share it wirelessly to a Samsung laptop, and my Android device.

The wired connection seems to work properly, and the wireless also works on my Android phone, but my laptop connects very slowly, and frequently drops the connection. It's a Samsung S3 laptop using Windows 7, with a built-in wifi adapter.

I have not changed any kind of network configuration on the system, because it worked very simple and straightforward with the previous router until that died on me, and I can't find any relevant settings in the router settings.

I have tried restarting the connection, the router, emptying the DNS-cache, browser cache, cookies, restarting the computer, but none of this seems to affect the performance of the connection.

What else could be causing this?

Thank you in advance.

*PS: A recent development is that when I connect the laptop to recharge, the internet connection works again. Is there some relation between Windows power saving and wireless functionality?*